# How to conditionally add a bootstrap class to a button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have upvote/downvote buttons on a site that I want to display differently depending on whether the user has upvoted the post or not. I'm using the acts_as_votable gem to handle votes so I could get a boolean value with @user.voted_up_on? @post. How can I conditionally add the bootstrap class of btn-success to the upvote button if a user has upvoted the post?
My upvote button looks like this:

```
<%= link_to upvote_path(:post => post), class: "btn btn-md", :method => :post do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add helper method:

```
def upvote_link(user, post)
  if user.voted_up_on?(post)
    btn_class = "btn btn-md btn-success"
  else
    btn_class = "btn btn-md"
  end

  link_to upvote_path(:post => post), class: btn_class, :method => :post do
    concat content_tag(:span, "", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up")
  end
end
```

And use in view

```
 <%= upvote_link(@user, @post) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using conditionals :D

```
button_classes = @user.voted_up_on?(@post) ? "btn btn-md btn-success" : "btn btn-md"
```

or

```
button_classes = ["btn", "btn-md"]
button_classes.push("btn-success") if @user.voted_up_on?(@post)
```

and use it, respectively

```
<%= link_to upvote_path(:post => post), class: button_classes, :method => :post do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to upvote_path(:post => post), class: button_classes.join(' '), :method => :post do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement to display different HTML depending on your boolean

```
<% btn_class = "btn btn-md" %>
<% btn_class = "btn btn-md btn-success" if @user.voted_up_on?(@post) %>
<%= link_to upvote_path(:post => post), class: btn_class, :method => :post do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
<% end %>
```